# How to Write Linq.Expression for IEnumerable.Any

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I am writing queries in my code which is `Linq to Sql`. I am not very familiar with expressions, I want to write an expression which checks if in a `IEnumerable` any of the item satisfies the condition

```
public class TestClass1
{
    // can be any number of properties, with diff names and types
    public string TestProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string TestProperty2 { get; set; }
    public List<TestClass1ExtraFieldValue> TestClass1ExtraFieldValueList { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass1ExtraFieldValue
{
    public TestClass1ExtraField TestClass1ExtraField { get; set; }

    // property names below are same in all classes which name ends with ExtraFieldValue
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass1ExtraField
{
    // property names are same in all classes which name ends with ExtraField
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass2
{
    // can be any number of properties, with diff names and types
    public string TestProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string TestProperty2 { get; set; }
    public List<TestClass2ExtraFieldValue> TestClass2ExtraFieldValueList { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass2ExtraFieldValue
{
    public TestClass2ExtraField TestClass2ExtraField { get; set; }

    // property names below are same in all classes which name ends with ExtraFieldValue
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass2ExtraField
{
    // property names are same in all classes  which name ends with ExtraField
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass3
{
    // can be any number of properties, with diff names and types
    public string TestProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string TestProperty2 { get; set; }
    public List<TestClass3ExtraFieldValue> TestClass3ExtraFieldValueList { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass3ExtraFieldValue
{
    public TestClass3ExtraField TestClass3ExtraField { get; set; }

    // property names below are same in all classes which name ends with ExtraFieldValue
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass3ExtraField
{
    // property names are same in all classes which name ends with ExtraField
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

// NOT a DB class
public class ExtraFieldClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

I have query classes like below:

```
public class TestClass1Query
{
    public string TestValue1;
    public string TestValue2;

    List<ExtraFieldClass> ExtraFieldsList { get; set; }

    public IQueryable GetQuery()
    {
        var query = GetTestClass1Values().Where(c=> c.TestProperty1==TestValue1 && c.TestProperty2 == TestValue2);
        // some condition checks
        foreach (var extraField in ExtraFieldsList)
        {
            switch (extraField.Type)
            {
                    case FieldType.Boolean:
                    {
                        var boolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass1ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass1ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass1ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.BoolValue == boolValue));
                        break;
                    }

                    case FieldType.DateTime:
                    {
                        var dateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass1ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass1ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass1ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.DateTimeValue == dateTimeValue));
                        break;
                    }

                    case FieldType.Text:
                    {
                        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass1ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass1ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass1ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.StringValue == stringValue));
                        break;
                    }

                    case FieldType.Integer:
                    {
                        var integerValue = Convert.ToInt32(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass1ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass1ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass1ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.IntValue == integerValue));
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        return query;
    }

    private IQueryable<TestClass1> GetTestClass1Values()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class TestClass2Query
{
    public string TestValue1;
    public string TestValue2;

    List<ExtraFieldClass> ExtraFieldsList { get; set; }

    public IQueryable GetQuery()
    {
        var query = GetTestClass2Values().Where(c => c.TestProperty1 == TestValue1 && c.TestProperty2 == TestValue2);
        // some condition checks
        foreach (var extraField in ExtraFieldsList)
        {
            switch (extraField.Type)
            {
                case FieldType.Boolean:
                    {
                        var boolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass2ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass2ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass2ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.BoolValue == boolValue));
                        break;
                    }

                case FieldType.DateTime:
                    {
                        var dateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass2ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass2ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass2ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.DateTimeValue == dateTimeValue));
                        break;
                    }

                case FieldType.Text:
                    {
                        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass2ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass2ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass2ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.StringValue == stringValue));
                        break;
                    }

                case FieldType.Integer:
                    {
                        var integerValue = Convert.ToInt32(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass2ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass2ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass2ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.IntValue == integerValue));
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        return query;
    }

    private IQueryable<TestClass2> GetTestClass2Values()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class TestClass3Query
{
    public string TestValue1;
    public string TestValue2;

    List<ExtraFieldClass> ExtraFieldsList { get; set; }

    public IQueryable GetQuery()
    {
        var query = GetTestClass3Values().Where(c => c.TestProperty1 == TestValue1 && c.TestProperty2 == TestValue2);
        // some condition checks
        foreach (var extraField in ExtraFieldsList)
        {
            switch (extraField.Type)
            {
                case FieldType.Boolean:
                    {
                        var boolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass3ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass3ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass3ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.BoolValue == boolValue));
                        break;
                    }

                case FieldType.DateTime:
                    {
                        var dateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass3ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass3ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass3ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.DateTimeValue == dateTimeValue));
                        break;
                    }

                case FieldType.Text:
                    {
                        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass3ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass3ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass3ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.StringValue == stringValue));
                        break;
                    }

                case FieldType.Integer:
                    {
                        var integerValue = Convert.ToInt32(extraField.Fieldvalue);
                        query = query.Where(c => c.TestClass3ExtraFieldValueList.Any(t => t.TestClass3ExtraField.Property1 == extraField.Property1
                                                                                      && t.TestClass3ExtraField.Property2 == extraField.Property2
                                                                                      && t.IntValue == integerValue));
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        return query;
    }

    private IQueryable<TestClass3> GetTestClass3Values()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now if you see my query classes, each has its own condition checks and for extra fields the logic is same only the names change. And I have 20 class similar to this. And I don't want to have the same repeated code every where. I searched and came to know that we can use `linq-expressions` to have a generic code for this.

I have no knowledge on writing expressions, Any suggestions or ways to achieve this?

Comment: Your code isn't working. And it isn't surely representative of your real code. There are too many "`public`" missing around... The `Match` function is wrongly written, so clearly you can't have tried it. And I'm not really sure you can really map a DB field to an `object` (`ObjectValue`) or that you can use interfaces for relationships with tables (`TestValue`)

Answer (score 0):

Linq you write is actually converted into SQL commands. In your case you have created rather complicated `Match` function that is just too complex to be translated into SQL automatically.

To get around that, you have to extract `switch` statement out of `Match` method and create query in-line:

```
var input = new Parameter();
// ...init input
query = query.Where(a => a.Property1 == "sometext");

switch(input.Type)
{
    Case bool:
        var boolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(input.ObjectValue);
        query = query.Where(a => a.Collection.Any(b => b.TestValue.C1 == input.Parameter1 && b.TestValue.C2 == input.Parameter && b.BoolValue == boolValue);
        break;
    Case dateTime :
        // convert to datetime and check
        var dateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(input.ObjectValue);
        query = query.Where(a=> a.Collection.Any(b => b.TestValue.C1 == input.Parameter1 && b.TestValue.C2 == input.Parameter && b.DateTimeValue == dateTimeValue );
        break;
    Case int:
        // convert to int and check
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Not the best looking code, but it should work.

**EDIT**

You can improve it by moving ugly part to separate function which can be reused:

```
public IQueryable<ITest2> ApplyFilterOnQuery(IQueryable<ITest2> query, Parameter input)
{
    switch(input.Type)
    {
        Case bool:
            var boolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(input.ObjectValue);
            query = query.Where(a => a.Collection.Any(b => b.TestValue.C1 == input.Parameter1 && b.TestValue.C2 == input.Parameter && b.BoolValue == boolValue);
            break;
        Case dateTime :
            // convert to datetime and check
            var dateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(input.ObjectValue);
            query = query.Where(a => a.Collection.Any(b => b.TestValue.C1 == input.Parameter1 && b.TestValue.C2 == input.Parameter && b.DateTimeValue == dateTimeValue );
            break;
        Case int:
            // convert to int and check
            // ...
            break;
    }
    return query;
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
var input = new Parameter();
// ...init input
query = query.Where(a => a.Property1 == "sometext");
query = ApplyFilterOnQuery(query, input);
```

Comment: My existing code is the same as what you said, i want it to make as generic code. I have many classes which uses IEnumerable<C> with different names. Instead of having this code for each and every class, i want it to be in base class.

Comment: I don't see any of that information in the original question. Anyway, see my updated answer on how to extract filtering in a seperate method.